# How hard drive internal encryption works?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I see many hard or SSD drives with internal encryption. They often claim to have 256 bit AES. So I can write the data to such disk and data will be stored encrypted. And I can read that data in decrypted state. But how this encryption prevents my data to be read by someone who'll steal my disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If manufacturer offers encryption, it's setting is done via software supplied with your hdd. It'll prompt you for a password or another method of authentication everytime you access your drive. But you have to enable this feature.

Advantage of internal encryption is speed of encryption, because it's likely hw based (depends on your manufacturer and type of drive).

Comment: Thank you. But how it behaves if i want to install such drive as a boot drive?

Comment: Insert drive, start computer, go to BIOS, select HDD password. The BIOS and the drive should chat. If you forget the password or someone removes the drives then the data on disk is unaccessable.

Comment: Encrytion key stays on HDD itself, but password protected. So it's still possible to access data, but only with valid password.